# vim: disable omnicompletion status messages (e.g. Pattern not found)

Tags: vim, autocomplete

In vim, is there any way to suppress omnicompletion messages like:

```
"-- Keyword completion (^N^P) Back at original"
"-- Keyword completion (^N^P) Pattern not found"
"-- Keyword completion (^N^P) match 1 of 3"
```

It's no big deal, just a bit distracting as I use it all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These messages are supposed to help you with moving through the completion candidates, so I'm afraid there's no way to turn them off.

Comment: looks like you are right. I guess I could edit sources and compile but for the time being, I'll just try to ignore the messages.

Comment: Sadly, The message is rather anoying. Plugins like YouCompleteMe or Neocomplete dosen't shows these message. I wonder how they do that

Comment: @rox: These plugins have custom completions, and those can (in recent Vim 7.4 versions) suppress the completion messages via special return codes (-2, -3, cp. `:help complete-functions`). It still cannot be turned off for built-in completions, as these messages are supposed to be helpful :-)

Comment: @IngoKarkat It can be turned of after vim 7.4.314, I found this [patch](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/WeBBjkXE8H8) by Shougo, add `setlocal shortmess+=c` would do the jub.

Answer (score 3):

It can be turned of after vim 7.4.314, I found this [patch](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/WeBBjkXE8H8) by Shougo, add `setlocal shortmess+=c` would supress these messages